# Array PHP, Check if exist multiple elements to another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a question about this:

[image]

I have two array, one is static, and one can be updated by the user...
I would like to check for every id from the static array if exist the id to the other array, and if exsist, do something, if doesn't exist (when finish to check) pass to other ID etc...

now, the arrays are these:

user array (the user unlock 2 achievement):

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [importance] => 0
      [achievement] => Array (
        [id] => 644081262362202
        [title] => Achievement 2
        [type] => game.achievement
        [url] => http://www.***.com/achievements/achievement2.html
      )
    )
    [id] => 104693166566570
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [importance] => 0
      [achievement] => Array (
        [id] => 968802826528055
        [title] => Achievement 1
        [type] => game.achievement
        [url] => http://www.***.com/achievements/achievement1.html
      )
    )
    [id] => 104023386633548
  )
)
```

the static Array (have 6 achievement saved):

```
Array (
  [0] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement2
    [title] => Achievement 2
    [id] => 644081262362202
  )
  [1] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement3
    [title] => Achievement 3
    [id] => 912599152147444
  )
  [2] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement5
    [title] => Achievement 5
    [id] => 913757345379232
  )
  [3] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement6
    [title] => Achievement 6
    [id] => 921989084564878
  )
  [4] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement1
    [title] => Achievement 1
    [id] => 968802826528055
  )
  [5] => Array (
    [data] => Array (
      [points] => 50
    )
    [description] => you unlock the achievement4
    [title] => Achievement 4
    [id] => 1149671038394021
  )
)
```

now, I use this script to echo the final output like the picture (results is the static array):

```php
if (empty($results)) {
  //echo 'noAchievement for the app';
} else {
  foreach ($results as $result) {
    $totalAchievementsApp .= ' [["' . "0" .'"],["'.$result[id] .'"],["'. $result[title] .'"],["'. $result[data][points]."]] ";
  }
}
```

now, How I can do to check inside the this script? I know I have to add another if inside the else to check if the ID is = to other ID, but I don't know how, I'm a little bit confused... I would like to check if the id of the static array exist in the other array, and if exsist, do this:

```
**$totalAchievementsApp .= ' [["' . "1" .'"],["'.$result[id] .'"],["'. $result[title] .'"],["'. $result[data][points]."]] ";**
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: You can sort by ID then loop both arrays moving forward the iterator of one until it match/surpass the other. You can iterate all id's on one array and check if those match any id in the second array (since php arrays are associative that's very easy to implement natively in the language)...

Comment: Does the 1 and 0 represent true and false, or does it represent the number of matches and thus 2 is a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to indicate for each entry in the static array whether its ID exists in the user array.

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to generate an array of all IDs in the user array. Then use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check if each static ID exists in that array. Set a value to 1 if its found and 0 if its not found.

For the sake of example, I've generated a new final output array. But you could just add the "found" value to each entry of the the static array.

```php
<?php

$static=array(
    array('point'=>50,'title'=>'TITLE 1','id'=>54632),
    array('point'=>50,'title'=>'TITLE 2','id'=>54344),
    array('point'=>50,'title'=>'TITLE 3','id'=>34225),
    array('point'=>50,'title'=>'TITLE 4','id'=>2323245),
    array('point'=>50,'title'=>'TITLE 5','id'=>23872445),
);
$user=array(
    array('id'=>2323245,'title'=>'TITLE 1','point'=>50),
    array('id'=>54344,'title'=>'TITLE 2','point'=>50),
    array('id'=>34225,'title'=>'TITLE 3','point'=>50)
);

$final=array();

foreach ($static as $entry) {
    $final[]=array(
        'found'=>in_array($entry['id'],array_column($user,'id'))?1:0,
        'id'=>$entry['id'],
        'title'=>$entry['title'],
        'point'=>$entry['point']
    );
}

echo"<pre>".print_r($final,true)."</pre>";
```

With your data, the output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 54632
            [title] => TITLE 1
            [point] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [found] => 1
            [id] => 54344
            [title] => TITLE 2
            [point] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [found] => 1
            [id] => 34225
            [title] => TITLE 3
            [point] => 50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [found] => 1
            [id] => 2323245
            [title] => TITLE 4
            [point] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 23872445
            [title] => TITLE 5
            [point] => 50
        )

)
```

---

### EDIT

Given the more complex structure of your actual arrays, I nested several `array_column` functions to access the deeper "data > achievement > id" keys in your user array:

```php
$user_achvmts=array_column(array_column(array_column($user,'data'),'achievement'),'id');
```

See the example below:

```
// initialize the "static" and "user" arrays

$static=array (
  0 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement2',
    'title' => 'Achievement 2',
    'id' => 644081262362202
  ),
  1 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement3',
    'title' => 'Achievement 3',
    'id' => 912599152147444
  ),
  2 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement5',
    'title' => 'Achievement 5',
    'id' => 913757345379232
  ),
  3 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement6',
    'title' => 'Achievement 6',
    'id' => 921989084564878
  ),
  4 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement1',
    'title' => 'Achievement 1',
    'id' => 968802826528055
  ),
  5 => array(
    'data' => array(
      'points' => 50
    ),
    'description' => 'you unlock the achievement4',
    'title' => 'Achievement 4',
    'id' => 1149671038394021
  )
);

$user=array(
  0=>array(
    'data' => array(
      'importance' => 0,
      'achievement' => array (
        'id' => 644081262362202,
        'title' => 'Achievement 2',
        'type' => 'game.achievement',
        'url' => 'http://www.***.com/achievements/achievement2.html'
      )
    ),
    'id' => 104693166566570
  ),
  1 => array (
    'data' => array (
      'importance' => 0,
      'achievement' => array (
        'id' => 968802826528055,
        'title' => 'Achievement 1',
        'type' => 'game.achievement',
        'url' => 'http://www.***.com/achievements/achievement1.html'
      )
    ),
    'id' => 104023386633548
  )
);

// build array of user achievement IDs
$user_achvmts=array_column(array_column(array_column($user,'data'),'achievement'),'id');

// generate final array, with "found" values
$final=array();

foreach ($static as $entry) {
    $final[]=array(
        'found'=>in_array($entry['id'],$user_achvmts)?1:0,
        'id'=>$entry['id'],
        'title'=>$entry['title'],
        'description'=>$entry['description'],
        'points'=>$entry['data']['points']
    );
}

echo"<pre>".print_r($final,true)."</pre>";
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [found] => 1
            [id] => 644081262362202
            [title] => Achievement 2
            [description] => you unlock the achievement2
            [points] => 50
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 912599152147444
            [title] => Achievement 3
            [description] => you unlock the achievement3
            [points] => 50
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 913757345379232
            [title] => Achievement 5
            [description] => you unlock the achievement5
            [points] => 50
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 921989084564878
            [title] => Achievement 6
            [description] => you unlock the achievement6
            [points] => 50
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [found] => 1
            [id] => 968802826528055
            [title] => Achievement 1
            [description] => you unlock the achievement1
            [points] => 50
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [found] => 0
            [id] => 1149671038394021
            [title] => Achievement 4
            [description] => you unlock the achievement4
            [points] => 50
        )

)
```

Note that `array_column` is only available in PHP >= 5.5.0. For older versions, see the [Recommended userland implementation for PHP lower than 5.5](https://github.com/ramsey/array_column/blob/master/src/array_column.php).

As an alternative to `array_column`, you could use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to build an array of the user IDs:

```php
$user_achvmts = array_map( function($v) {return $v['data']['achievement']['id'];}, $user);
```

Or even just iterate through the user array:

```
$user_achvmts=[];
foreach ($user as $v) { $user_achvmts[]=$v['data']['achievement']['id']; }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply, I almost solve my problem, the string:           'found'=>in_array($entry['id'],array_column($userAch,'id'))?1:0, doesn't find any id, the found will be 0 to all... I access the id of the user like this: $result[data][achievement][id] but if I copy that, doesn't works... thank you very much

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the structure of your arrays. Please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used another method to get works, but with your is better, less code, and works perfect!! thank you very much :)